# how to store state in mvc application, in such a way that state can be used by newly spun threads

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a webmvc application. I store state via RequestContextHolder, which stores the attributes in the HttpServletRequest object. This way I don't have to pass around the state in every class/methods.
Retrieved using RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()

In my http request processing, I want to create new threads to process long running tasks. I want the state to be accessible in the new threads.

Because the HttpServletRequest object is reused, the state gets lost as soon as the http response is returned. So the long running thread can't access the state.

What is the best practice to store the state in such a way that newly created threads can access them too.

P.S. database & filesystem are not an option. due to performance and other reasons.

I tried setting inheritableRequestAttributesHolder to true in RequestContextFilter , so that the attributes are inherited to the new thread. But when the new thread runs longer than the original http thread, it can't access that data anymore. Understandably the HttpServletRequest object is recycled.